# Does C# HashSet check duplicate by Equals then by GetHashCode?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashset

Just want somebody to confirm my thinking, I tried different combinations of overriding **Equals** and **GetHashCode** in **Foo** class:

```
class Foo
{
    static int n;
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return true;
        //return false;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 0;
        //return n++;
    }
}
```

then test result showed:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HashSet<Foo> set = new HashSet<Foo>();
        Foo f1 = new Foo();
        Foo f2 = new Foo();

        Console.WriteLine(f1.Equals(f2));
        set.Add(f1);
        Console.WriteLine(set.Contains(f2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

1. When Equals is true, Contains is determined by GetHashCode;
2. When Equals is false, Contains is always false.

So **Contains** is determined by Equals then by GetHashCode, am I right?

Comment: You can easily confirm your thinking by adding a `Console.WriteLine` to each overridden method to see the order in which they show up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other way around. First `GetHashCode()` is called. This is used to give a hash code (hence the name) which is used to determine where internally the object should be stored.

There's no guarantee that hash codes will be unique (and besides, it gets reduced further) so there could be more than one object stored with the same hash (the more, the worse the performance, but that's another matter). So after finding possible matches `Equals` is used to confirm the match.

So `Contains` depends on `GetHashCode()` first, and then on `Equals()`.

That the two work in tandem is why you must always override one if you override the other, and always override your `GetHashCode()` in such a way that any two objects that would consider each other `Equal()` will have the same code.

Comment: And the easiest way to ensure that two objects which would consider each other equal have the same hash code is usually to have your `Equals()` method call your `GetHashCode()` method.

Comment: Providing a quote from the relevant MSDN docs (and link) would be ideal to better document your post. This should also help others to verify that this is the documented behavior rather than an implementation detail that might differ under a different environment/implementation (e.g. Mono).

Comment: Jon, it's probably also important to mention that the `GetHashCode` value should not change over the lifetime of the object.

Comment: Short version: `public override bool Equals(object obj) { return this.GetHashCode() == obj.GetHashCode()}`

Comment: If we don't override `Equals`, then what it will do internally? I mean, the default process of confirming back the equality.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that's completely bogus. Two equal objects must have equal hashcodes, but two different objects MAY have the same hashcode

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Suppose that `long` implemented `Equals` like that. `long` has far more values than possible hash codes, so different values comparing equal would be unavoidable. Agreed with Jcl, this is exceptionally wrong, you really don't understand how hash codes are supposed to work (and do work).

Comment: @Bharadwaj the default `Equals` for non-anonymous reference types considers each such object equal only to itself. The default for anonymous types calls `Equals` on all matching fields. The default for value types does much the same but via reflection, so overriding is generally a good idea for performance even when the default gives the desired result. The default `GetHashCode` for each matches the requirements of the `Equals`.

Comment: @Enigmativity that's wrong. An object must not change in a way that affects its `GetHashCode` (or it's `Equals`) while being used as a key, but if an object changed otherwise in a way that changed what it was considered equal to then the hash code **must** change. Of course, those two requirements can come into conflict, with the easiest way to resolve it being to only use immutable objects as keys, so the issue of what to do when they change never coming up.

Comment: "but if an object changed otherwise in a way that changed what it was considered equal to then the hash code **must** change" -- I'm sure you mean "should". There's no requirement for it to change. Even ignoring hash collisions which are unavoidable, there are some cases where you can ignore a property in hash code calculations that you do use in equality checks, for instance when in the vast majority of cases, the other properties you use for equality checks are typically uniquely identifying already.

Comment: @hvd I mean *must*, but considering that as including a fresh calculation that coincidentally happens to result in the same value as before as a "change".